# How to properly write a photo into memory and get the URI (Honeycomb)?

Tags: android, save, uri, android-3.0-honeycomb, photo

I'm building an app that takes a photo and then e-mails it. For this I have to save it into the device's memory. The problem I'm getting is that while the app writes my file, it crashes at this particular line of code:

```
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,    Uri.fromFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
```

Lower you have the entire function and code:

```
    private void takePicture(){
    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpg");
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,    Uri.fromFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
       if(requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
           picture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           pictureView.setImageBitmap(picture);

           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "Picture");
           values.put(Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, "picture_ID");
           values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "");
           values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

           pictureUri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
           OutputStream outstream;

           try{
               outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(pictureUri);
               picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);
               outstream.close();
           }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
   }
```

If I comment that line out, the app doesn't crash anymore. I need to get the photo's URI so I can then email it.

Any help from you guys more experienced out there would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File path = new File("/mnt/sdcard/YourDirectory");
path.mkdirs();
String fileName = "yourfile.jpg";
File file = new File(path, name);
camera.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivityForResult(camera, PICTURE_RESULT);



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (PICTURE_RESULT == requestCode && Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                 android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            //////////   TASK TODO After result    //////////
        } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "sdcard not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } 
}
```